# XSLT get part of string or url

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm getting the following XML-element back in an XML file. From this element I need to retrieve the URL information.

```
<Page SmallImage="" LargeImage="" Icon="" MenuText="Text" MouseOver="" Image="" 
ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" 
Href="Default.aspx?ID=27&GroupID=GROUP11" 
FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/assortiment/group/category/text.aspx" Title="" NavigationTag="" 
RelativeLevel="4" Sort="1" LastInLevel="True" ChildCount="0" class="L4" ID="18" 
AreaID="1" InPath="False" Active="False" AbsoluteLevel="4"/>
```

As visible in the example above the attribute 'Href' contains an GroupID.

```
Href="Default.aspx?ID=27&GroupID=GROUP11"
```

Now I want to concatenate the GROUPID of the URL with the value from the FriendlyHref attribute. Is it possible to get this value using XSLT1.0?

The result I would like to get is;

```
/nl-nl/assortiment/group/category/text.aspx?Group=GROUP11
```

I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981175/is-it-possible-to-slice-off-the-end-of-a-url-with-xslt-1-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995761/xslt-get-file-name-from-url) topic here on stackoverflow, but these examples didn't gave me any results at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `GroupID` is always the last argument of the query string, you can use [substring-after()](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring-after.html) to extract the value. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="Page">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@FriendlyHref, '?Group=', substring-after(@Href, 'GroupID='))" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Superb! Exactly what I needed. Good solution in this case, because the GroupID indeed is always the last argument.

Comment: What if the XML is this: `<Provider><a title="" href="/pro.aspx?id=0098">And, Jo</a></Provider>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307212/how-to-get-certain-part-of-a-link-in-xslt

Comment: @Search, `match="Provider/a"`?

Comment: I have added a detailed question, if you don't mind looking please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation correctly obtains the query string value, regardless of its location** (at the start, in the midle or at the end of the string containing all query strings):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="vQueryStrings"
         select="concat('&amp;',substring-after(@Href, '?'), '&amp;')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vWantedValue"   select=
     "substring-before
         (substring-after($vQueryStrings, '&amp;GroupID='),
         '&amp;')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@FriendlyHref, '?',$vWantedValue)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the provided XML document** (slightly corrected to make more challenging and also it wellformed):

```
<Page SmallImage="" LargeImage="" Icon=""
     MenuText="Text" MouseOver="" Image=""
     ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Allowclick="True"
     ShowInSitemap="True"
     Href="Default.aspx?ID=27&amp;GroupID=GROUP11&amp;foo=bar"
     FriendlyHref="/nl-nl/assortiment/group/category/text.aspx"
     Title="" NavigationTag=""  RelativeLevel="4" Sort="1"
     LastInLevel="True" ChildCount="0" class="L4" ID="18"
     AreaID="1" InPath="False" Active="False" AbsoluteLevel="4"/>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
/nl-nl/assortiment/group/category/text.aspx?GROUP11
```

**Finally**: A fully generic/parameterized solution, that accepts any query string name as a parameter and produces its value:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:call-template name="getQueryString"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="getQueryString">
  <xsl:param name="pHrefName" select="'Href'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pQSName" select="'GroupID'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vQueryStrings"
         select="concat('&amp;',
                        substring-after(@*[name()=$pHrefName], '?'),
                        '&amp;')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vWantedValue"   select=
     "substring-before
         (substring-after($vQueryStrings, concat('&amp;', $pQSName, '=')),
         '&amp;')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vWantedValue"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the XML document above, the wanted result is produced**:

```
GROUP11
```