# How to get certain part of a link in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<col>
    <Html>
        <root>
            <Pro>
                <a title="" href="/pro.aspx?id=0098">And, Jo</a>
            </Pro>
        </root>
    </Html>
    <Html>
        <root>
            <Pro>
                <a title="" href="/pro.aspx?id=0098">And, Jo</a>
            </Pro>
        </root>
    </Html>
    <Html>
        <root>
            <Pro>
                <a title="" href="/pro.aspx?id=0098">And, Jo</a>
            </Pro>
        </root>
    </Html>
</col>
```

How can I get the `0098` from the above and create a link using XSLT.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="dispSpec" match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="col/Html/root">
            <div class="justPad">
                <a class="link1" href="anotherpage.aspx?id={0098}">Click Here</a>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use:

```
substring-after(@href, 'id=')
```

You haven't provided any context, so there's no more than that.

---

### Edit:

***(In response to your edit)***

Try changing your template  to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="col/Html/root">
        <div class="justPad">
            <a class="link1" href="anotherpage.aspx?id={substring-after(Pro/a/@href, 'id=')}">Click Here</a>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Note**:

1. Your stylesheet creates a document with several `div` elements and no single root element. Perhaps that's fine with the target application, but it needs to be pointed out;
2. I don't see why your template needs to be named; are you calling it by name at any point (doesn't seem very likely)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I create the link? I added more information.